# Asp 5 ServerVariables

Tags: asp.net-core, server-variables

I am in the progress of rewriting some code to work with ASP 5.

The old code does the following:

```
string Local_IP=Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"];
string HTTP_reverse_VIA = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REVERSE_VIA"];
```

How do I get the corresponding information from ASP 5?

Comment: did you get final solution for ***ASP.NET 5*** ? _Request.ServerVariables_ obsolete ?

Answer (score 0):

HttpContext has the GetFeature method, using this method we can get feature information.

Here we are want to get Server Variables of IIS; check project.json "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS" is used for running ASP.NET 5.

We have to use GetFeature of 'Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS' which contains Server variables feature. use the below code

```
var varibleFeature = Context.GetFeature<Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS.Features.IServerVariablesFeature>();

            if (varibleFeature != null)
            {
                var valuesList = varibleFeature.ServerVariables;

                //read through valuesList dictionary for Server Variables
            }
```

Since I was running on IIS Express, it gave few variables but not the one mentioned in your question.

Please deploy it on IIS and explore more.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.


I have now tried to deploy the code to our test server, but the only ServerVariable available is "IIS_UrlRewriteModule" :-(


Any idea why there are no other ServerVariable available? Is this an issue with the ASP5 IIS integration or are we missing something?

Comment: Oh thats great, I had got this ServerVariable too. I am not sure about remaining variables, maybe they are not implemented yet as things are in beta still both ASP.NET 5 and IIS.

Comment: @RenéMadsen - Please refer this link, this might give some directions. Will let you know if I find it http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/setting-http-request-headers-and-iis-server-variables

Comment: `GetFeature` is not (or no longer) a method of `HttpContext`.